# Spring Jackson @JsonFilter Examples

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

Does anyone know any examples of using Jackson‘s @JsonFilter annotations in Spring MVC to enable a caller to specify a return type at runtime?

I‘ve got a JSON API that I would like to keep simple by offering methods like getEntity, preferably taking some argument or other to define what view of the entity to return.

Comment: I don't think `@JsonFilter` is designed to help with type conversion or to specify type information (`@JsonTypeInfo` would be). Have you seen something to suggest it would be useful? For what it's worth, here is one general example of how to use Jackson `@JsonFilter` annotation: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureJsonFilter

Comment: another article on the same topic http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/09/entry_461.html

Comment: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureJsonFilter

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like @JsonView annotation. It was not supported on Spring but this issue is solved!
Follow [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/be0b69cbf1377e3fa8d8abc94f24274f4d0945b2)

> **Add support for Jackson serialization views**
>
> Spring MVC now supports Jackon's serialization views for rendering
>   different subsets of the same POJO from different controller
>   methods (e.g. detailed page vs summary view).
>   Issue: SPR-7156

This is the [SPR-7156](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-7156).

> **Status: Resolved**
>
> **Description**
>
> Jackson's JSONView annotation allows the developer to control which aspects of a method are serialiazed. With the current implementation, the Jackson view writer must be used but then the content type is not available. It would be better if as part of the RequestBody annotation, a JSONView could be specified.

***Available on [Spring ver >= 4.1](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-jsonview)***

### UPDATE

Follow this [link](https://spring.io/blog/2014/12/02/latest-jackson-integration-improvements-in-spring). Explains with an example the @JsonView annotation.